# Timing in JavaScript: Finding a way to make setInterval alternate time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a web page for a class project, and specifically, an "about us" page that iterates through pictures and descriptions of the team members. On the view, I have this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $("#about-img").attr('src', img_src[i]);
  $("#name").html(names[i]);
  $("#description").html(descriptions[i]);
  i = (i + 1) % img_src.length;
}, 8000);
```

This effectively iterates, however, sometimes descriptions are longer than others. Is there any way to wait longer, the longer the description is? Something simple would be

```
waits(descriptions[i].length * 50);
```

Right in the setInterval function, but javascript has no way of doing that. What can I do? setTimeout is asynchronous, and I cannot influence the second parameter of setInterval from the scope of the first.

Answer (score 3):

Use setTimeout instead of an interval

```
function changeMessage () {
    $("#about-img").attr('src', img_src[i]);
    $("#name").html(names[i]);
    $("#description").html(descriptions[i]);
    i = (i + 1) % img_src.length;
    window.setTimeout(changeMessage, descriptions[i].length * 50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you might do the timer(s) involved:

To do it just once after some time:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){alert('test');}, 3000);//3 seconds
```

Do it forever:

```
window.setInterval(function(alert('test');){}, 3000);//do it forever in 3 second intervals
```